# How do I retrieve email message body content that supports dark mode from microsoft graph api

Tags: xamarin.forms, microsoft-graph-api, android-dark-theme, darkmode

I am trying to use microsoft graph API to build my email client app using xamarin.forms for both android and ios. My apps support dark theme. Graph API is giving me the Html result for the body content and the styles are only light mode supportive.

Is there a way to get email message body content that supports dark mode ?

Comment: Thats interesting ask. From Graph API perspective, i dont remember there is any way exists. I would suggest you to file an uservoice so that they can consider Microsoft implementing it. Here's the link that i can remember, 
 go ahead and create new one. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359602&query=dark%20mode

Comment: @Dev Thanks for the comment and the link. I have filed a request here https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41994628-dark-mode